# Kendo Grid with multiple child not binding on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik Kendo UI razor grid and have implemented hierarchical grid which is

- Parent

  - field 1
  - field2
  - child grid 1

    - child grid 2 (inline edit)

Now the grid displays data well and has inline editing for child 2, this is where it gets complicated, when I click on form save button (outside grid) the entire view-model for grid (i.e. child 1 grid and child 2 grid) displays null in controller.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Show the code please.